# free SMS API/Gateway? is there any?

Tags: sms

I think this is not the appropriate site to ask this question, but I don't have any choices because Google can't answer my question. Or if there is the WOT evaluation is very low. So legitimacy can't be assured.

Is there any **free SMS API/Gateway** you can suggest? Because our thesis (E-commerce) have SMS Features. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Free SMS API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/238579/free-sms-api)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some free “email SMS” gateways that some networks (a relatively small number) provide and they are quite legitimate but...

These gateways accept the lowest priority traffic and operate very slow 
and are not suitable for commercial text marketing. Some do appear to work http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SMS_gateways but be warned they are subject to change and usually unsupported by the networks.

You would need any mobile you sent to, to opt into your service.

There are some wordpress plug ins that use free email to SMS gateways like the following

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/mediaburst-email-to-sms/

They rely on the wordpress community of users to keep them updated on which networks are working at that time.